# libreoffice calc bug or missconfiguration prevents IF statment to work on the version 6.4.5.2

Tags: if-statement, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I cant make the if statement work on 'LibreOffice 6.4.5.2 40(Build:2)', lubuntu 20.04. But it works on 'LibreOffice 6.4.2.2 40(Build:2)', lubuntu 20.04, of other cpu.

Cell A1 : `1`

Cell A2 formula : `=if(a1=1;2;3)`

Cell A2 should returns : `2`

But returns : `#NAME?`

This same formula works on the other cpu. So its either a problem with the configuration or a bug of the version 6.4.5.2 , right ? I did reinstalled the libreoffice calc using the terminal, but this error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Although it didnt explains why it happens, upgrade the libreoffice calc to the last version (6.4.6.2) from the official site solve the issue.